# How to optimize my code using temple method or generic method or other method?Now I have to write the similar code three times

Tags: java, generics

Now I want to send the message to the people which may be student,teacher or schoolmaster,and all of them have the phone,name and availdSendMsgCount.Before  send the message which means insert the data to database,I have to judge whether them can be sent or not.So I write the code like this:

```
if(sendType=SendType.student){
 List<Student> students=tStudentServiceImpl.queryByParam(conditionMap);
         sendPhoneCout=students.size(); 
         checkSendNumber(availdSendMsgCount,sendPhoneCout); 
Log log=logMsgSend(content,sendPhoneCout,sendType); 
         for (Student vo : students)      
 sendMsgItem(content,vo.getPhone(),vo.getName(),vo.getId(),log.getId()); 
}
 else if(sendType=SendType.teacher){
 List<Teacher> teachers=tTeacherServiceImpl.queryByParam(conditionMap);
         sendPhoneCout=teachers.size(); 
         checkSendNumber(availdSendMsgCount,sendPhoneCout); 
     Log log=logMsgSend(content,sendPhoneCout,sendType); 
         for (Teacher vo : teachers)      
   sendMsgItem(content,vo.getPhone(),vo.getName(),vo.getId(),log.getId()); 
}
else{
  List<Schoolmaster>  schoolmasters=tSchoolmasterServiceImpl.queryByParam(conditionMap);
         sendPhoneCout=schoolmasters.size(); 
         checkSendNumber(availdSendMsgCount,sendPhoneCout); 
     Log log=logMsgSend(content,sendPhoneCout,sendType); 
         for (Schoolmaster vo : schoolmasters)      
   sendMsgItem(content,vo.getMasterPhone(),vo.getMasterName(),vo.getId(),log.getId()); 
 }
```

I think this code is bad.But how to optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create an interface and implement it in your dao classes, so each of them will behave differently.

```
public interface NameMe {
      void sendMsgItem(content, Integer logId); // it's not clear the type of content
}
```

There is the method

```
// replace T with type of 'conditionMap' object, it's not clear from your code
public static void getAndSendMessageItems(Function<T, List<NameMe>> serviceFunc,
        T conditionMap, Integer availdSendMsgCount, SendType sendType) { 
    List<NameMe> values = serviceFunc.apply(conditionMap);
    Integer sendPhoneCout = values.size(); 
    checkSendNumber(availdSendMsgCount, sendPhoneCout); 
    Log log = logMsgSend(content, sendPhoneCout, sendType); 
    for (NameMe i : values) {     
         i.sendMsgItem(content, log.getId());            
    }
}
```

And call it in your if/else

```
Function<T, List<NameMe>> serviceFunc = null; 
if (SendType.student.equals(sendType)) {
    serviceFunc = tStudentServiceImpl::queryByParam;
} else if (SendType.teacher.equals(sendType)) {
    serviceFunc = tTeacherServiceImpl::queryByParam;
} else {
    serviceFunc = tSchoolmasterServiceImpl::queryByParam;
}
getAndSendMessageItems(serviceFunc, conditionMap, availdSendMsgCount, sendType);
```

However, if your services implement the same interface, you even don't need to use `Function<T, List<NameMe>>`, you can just pass service via interface object.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am using jdk7,may be it is not work on jdk7.Is it  right?

Comment: @flower, yes `Function` class was introduced in 1.8. Than you should deal with implementing interface in your `StudentService`, `TeacherService`, `SchoolmasterService`. Currently you have very poor architecture :(

Answer (score 1):

When Schoolmaster, Teacher and Student implement the same interface or superclass then you could write one method with List as parameter which is doing all the stuff and that is called in each of your three cases.

On the other hand, why do you have three different classes? They seem to have exactly the same methods. Wouldn't one be enough with a type parameter that is deciding what kind of type it is?

Comment: They are three table,and they have the other differenct filed.

Comment: May be temple method can do this,just like T or <T>.But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Could you add an interface that all three classes are implementing?

Comment: Do you mean add an interface that all three classes are implementing or add an interface that all three classeserviceImpl are implementing??

Comment: I meant let Schoolmaster, Teacher and Student implement the same interface that has at least the methods `getPhone()`, `getName()` and `getId()`. Then add a method `sendMsgItem(List<? extends YourNewInterface>)` that contains all the stuff that you have within your if statement (except the call to the service). At last call this method from your original method like this `if(sendType=SendType.student){
  sendMsgItem(tStudentServiceImpl.queryByParam(conditionMap));
}`

About the other solution(letting the services implement the same interface) Sergey Prokofiev already wrote something above.